# onTouch() can't draw canvas

Tags: android, canvas, draw

onDraw(Canvas canvas) works automatically. In this view onTouch() method listens for touching the screen. I need to redraw the rectangle when I click on the screen but it isn't drawing the rectangle canvas.

```
public class Viewer extends View implements OnTouchListener{

    public Viewer(Context context) {
        super(context);

        .............
        ..............
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);              
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){  
        super .onDraw(canvas);
        drawBackGround(imgObj.bg01, canvas);    
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

        Canvas c = new canvas();
        c.drawRect(.......);    //<------ It's work but it isn't redraw
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: call `invalidate()` after `c.drawRect(.......);`

Comment: thanks – rIHaN JiTHiN  but it's not work

Comment: You have to draw on canvas in method onDraw only. Remove from onTouch

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Canvas mCanvas;
 @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){  

        mCanvas = canvas;
        drawBackGround(imgObj.bg01, mCanvas);
        super.onDraw(mCanvas);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

        mCanvas.drawRect(.......); 
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: it's disappear. I try to check by breakpoint. I found mCanvas is null.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add `mCanvas=new Canvas();` in the constructor. Yes you are right we should have only one `canvas`.

Comment: so is this not possible?